# Как загрузить obb?

Tags: android

1. Как загрузить obb в консоль маркета?
2. Стоит ли вообще использовать OBB в Google Play, Андроид? Или же использовать какой-нибудь левый хостинг при покупке контентов?

Answer (score 1):

Надо паковать ваш OBB (понятия не имею, что это такое, кстати) в [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) и далее выкладывать в маркет этот файл, обложив его выкачивание покупкой.

Как-то так.

P.S. Но я почему-то думаю, что вы это не одолеете. :)

Comment: @Barmaley ♦, Покупку то одолел же все таки)), obb создавать написано как, осталось только научиться хостингом пользоваться...Да вот инфу то где взять не знаю

Comment: @Futurama с нетерпением жду релиза вашей программы. Очень хочу посмотреть на неё.

Comment: @argamidon, Я тоже xD

Comment: @Futurama, может быть, выложите бета-версию?

Comment: @SuperCreeper, чтобы её выложить, надо obb добваить, иначе без контента это прога ничто

Есть идеи какие нибудь?